# Single pulse at low/high transit

Tags: circuit-analysis

Is there a basic circuit to trigger a single short pulse when turning a device an? Something like a circuit providing the derivative of a signal?

Comment: The name of such a circuit is "monostable multivibrator" or "one shot".

Comment: Yes there is a circuit to provide the derivative of (differentiate) a signal. It's called a differentiator.

Comment: A cap (plus resistor) will differentiate both directions of change (with a sign change, obviously.) One of those two can be clipped with a diode, I suppose. I personally prefer the 74121/74123 approach. Clean, programmable width, etc. If you go with the cap+resistor+diode, you may want to buffer before and after. What kinds of parts do you have available or are otherwise familiar with using? And how fast does your device "turn on?" (Does the power supply have a gradual rise to its rail?)

Answer (score 0):

Connect one end of a capacitor to your signal. Connect the other end to a resistor, and the other end of the resistor to ground. Take your output as the voltage across the resistor.

The current through a capacitor is proportional to the derivative of the voltage across it, while the voltage across the resistor is proportional to the current through it. The resistor voltage won't quite be the derivative of your input voltage, but it will give you the narrow pulse you want.